# Best practice for question with no answer

Tags: support

As far as I know...a question I've asked can't be solved.

What is the best practice?

- Delete the question
- Write an answer stating no solution found (and thus leaving the question available for potential future answers)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mike, Leave the questions open. One-day, Some-day someone will hit the question, and if it has answer for it then will reply it.

You may know thats on SE we have Late answer badges.

Answer (score 4):

In 2010 I asked a question on StackOverflow which, by then, had a no answer. Or more correct, what I asked about didn't exist. Five years later, the .NET library had evolved and the thing I asked about was developed.

I'm not to take credit for that Microsoft implemented my missing feature, but it tells us we should leave questions open, as they may be resolved in the future.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262947/is-there-a-built-in-binary-search-tree-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 2):

I've always found it's best to leave it open, unanswered. If someone comes across it down the road that has a solution in mind or has the same issue, they can then answer. If it's a relevant answer, you can decide then to award the solution to that person who answered.

I've had questions that I left opened that I answered legitimately months and months down the road that I'm hoping helped those that may have the same problem.