# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers. Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our back up questions for a total of 6 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/e1b81785-452f-442c-8a72-6b7d1e3cac21/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

---

> 1. How would you improve the voting rate on the site? Since the famous meta post [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters) was asked back in 2013 I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes. Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio. How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the site?
> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 4. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 5. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 6. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: Hi @Grace , Thank you so much for your great effort, I have one question please, regarding the nomination process, I understood that the candidate has two tasks, 1. he should answer the above questions on this thread. 2. Nominate himself at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election Is it correct?

Comment: Yes the HOW and WHAT are important, But I really would like to know WHY people want to be a moderator and are willing to invest 2 hours a day here. Is it Ego? Status? More chance for a better Job?

Comment: i think it is community service, take it as community, everybody investing the time in their capacity here so, If one feel he can server community better with more responsibility then why not.the same rule apply to all communities either digital or local. Yes once u have an honor this type of honor then people thing u are more responsible and discipline and good team player / leader. I think moderator dont get paid here but spend quality time here to gain the honor and get some respect. I am here since 2013 but many of my friends told my reply solve their issue, this which give me relaxation.

Comment: Do you candidates think anyone can become a Moderator; even someone who signed up yesterday? If not, what is the minimum "score" required to become a Moderator?

Comment: In my opinion no, because he should spend sometime in community and take part of the activities to understand the rule of the community. Once he is familiar and get enough education then he is eligible. minimum score is difficult i think i would go with current community eligibility criteria.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, can we nominate somebody(not ourselves) to become a moderator ?

Comment: I am new could I nominate myself?

Comment: You could, but users will vote on the amount of dedication you have to the site.

Answer (score 16):

I'm [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas). I would like to share my humble thoughts by answering the below questions.

> 1. How would you improve the voting rate on the site? Since the famous meta post [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters) was asked back in 2013 I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes. Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio. How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the site?

I totally agree with this question, Although the voting is a simple task and the SE users are not lazy. But I think the main reason for this problem is the lack of an ideal guidance for the voting process and its importance, as well as the loss of some kind of encouragement that I think is much simpler than the voting process.

To overcome this problem I think we should find a simple way to guide new users as well as create different kinds of encouragement and appreciation for old users.

**Let's start with old users and propose how we can find innovative ways to encourage them:**

- Like edits, Why the community didn't grant a 1 point for each upvote for the users who have reputation less than 2000 points? by the way, The maximum number of upvote is already limited with 30 upvotes per day, In this way, most users will exhaust the voting balance in order to get 30 points :).Meanwhile, the upvote rate will be increased.
- I also propose to prepare a weekly, monthly, quarterly and annual report for **The Most Active Contributors** regardless the type of contributions (Edits, Votes, reputations ... etc). *(This information can be easily obtained from SE leader board at [site statistics](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters).)*

[image]

**This weekly, monthly, quarterly and annual report will include the following awards**

- The 5/10 top contributors award
- The 5/10 top editors award.
- The 5/10 top voters award.
- The 5/10 best questions award.
- The 5/10 best answers award.
- The Most "asked questions" award.
- The Most "provided answers" award.
- The Most upvoted questions award.
- The Most upvoted answers award.
- and other awards based on awesome contributions ...etc.

**Once the report has been prepared, one of the moderators (or the Stack Exchange social media admin) should do the following:**

- Share & tweet this report via the social media like Twitter and facebook.
- Prepare an email template based on each award that should be used to send an appreciation email for the top contributes.(I am ready to prepare this template regardless I selected as moderator or not)

> Based on the achievements of each contributor, the community grants
>   the Excellence Award **SE-MVP** quarterly and annually. I think the
>   above suggestions will increase the positive contributions on SE!

**Regarding the new users**, we should guide them to know

- How to use the site?
- What's the importance of badges?
- How to appreciate the provided answers by upvoting the helpful answers and accept the correct answer? **This should be highlighted when the user asks a new question**.

I also proposed the following:

- The registration process should be a mandatory step for all user.

  - The unregistered user can see questions and answers but can not ask new questions or comment on an existing question before registering on the site.
- During the registration process, the terms of use must be highlighted.
- Once the registration process has been completed, the tour instructions https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour should be highlighted clearly and simply.

[image]

- The new user's tab should be exploited to monitor the behavior and performance of new users and try to guide them.

[image]

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I will appreciate and respect his wonderful efforts and at the same time, I will apply the community rules to everyone with some wisdom and without any distinction.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Mutual respect is the secret of any team's success. So I will respect his opinion. I will try to communicate with him personally to find out his point of view and try to round up views.

So I suggest creating a **closed** chat room for moderators to discuss such issues.

> 4. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Besides what I mentioned earlier. I think the main Moderators functions are,

- Serve the community with all his strength.
- Guide the new users to stay on SE and help them to use the site easily.
- Enhance and improve the site contents.
- Approve/reject flags, suggested edits ...... etc.
- Suggest new ideas that help to simplify and enhance the community.
- Upvoting The correct answers and guide the question owner to mark it in case it helped him. so I suggest adding a new feature that allows the moderator to be able to propose an answer as a correct answer by upvoting it and remember the question owner to take action for the provided answers.
- Find problems and fix them if he can,
- Trace the user's behavior and track abnormal actions.
- Keep a friendly environment for users by Communicating and answering users queries as soon as possible, so I suggest besides the META forum, we should have a chat room to can reach and ask the moderators directly. this will activate the aim of chat rooms again.
- Continue answering the technical questions.

> 5. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers, and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I usually review my old answers and comments to enhance my old answers and remove any comments that are not suitable. I do this weekly specifically on Saturday where there is no heavy load in the community.

> 6. In what way do you feel that being a moderator make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Helping people is a great feeling especially when you consider this as alms for your knowledge, I think anyone contributes in any community will feel (after some time) he does awesome work rather than he try to gain points, so in my opinion, the reputation is important meanwhile helping people is most important and should be our main goal.

As for the ways that will make me more effective, they are many but the main way as I mentioned earlier is the appreciation of valuable contributions and successful attempts, I also wish supervisors to allow us some of their precious time to talk to them directly. it will lead to a friendly working environment.

Finally, I would like to thank our current loyal moderators, I really appreciate the work done by them, I also learned a lot from their guidelines and I still learn.

Comment: SharePoint.SO is nothing in the Global SO universe. Some of the changes you propose are not possible without changing SO.

Comment: Moderators must carry great responsibilities in terms of their **behavior**, **communication skills**, and **how smartly they handle conflicts or difference of opinion with good and polite language**. Do you think you need any improvement in these points? Will you be able to do justice to the community? Do you have ability to be polite and calm nature when needed?

Comment: Dear @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thank you for your feedback :) Could you please specify the changes that impossible to be applied? I think Most Contributor report, SE-MVP and sharing on social media will be done manually, and the upvote point is already applied for Edit it's the same process, but I agree with you the proposed as an answer will require some changes! so let's work together to specify which option is applicable and **will add value** or not applicable? appreciate your time!

Comment: Dear @AsadRefai , First of all,  I would like to thank you for these great and important questions, Regarding: Do you think you need any improvement in these points? 
I think self-improvement is very important to any successful person
It is a continuous and intuitive process and no one can evaluate himself or determine that he does not need to improve and strengthen his skills so I think to be a successful person and maintain this success I need to improve my strengths and strengthen my weak points every moment.

Comment: Regarding: Will you be able to do justice to the community? 

This is also a great question, I believe that achieving justice requires not only the knowledge of the laws that govern us, but also the need for wisdom and mutual respect. Therefore, I believe justice will be achieved if we respect and follow the laws that govern us and trust those who implement them.

Comment: Regarding: Do you have the ability to be polite and calm nature when needed?

Calm and respect must be present at any time and not only when needed. I have faced many situations since joining this community and I think I have not harmed anyone or underestimated the work of anyone.

As I mentioned earlier there must be mutual respect and appreciation for what is being done to serve this community.

Comment: So you wrote a nice political program, without decent research into what StackOverflow can do (and most of all what can NOT be changed) Nice words to woo people into voting for you and now you want someone else to do the grunt work and list where your political text needs some tweaking? What is in it for me? Can I call myself deputy-Moderator then?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman To become a moderator, this is an honor for everyone and big responsibilities. But I do not write all these words to get some electoral votes. I proposed this a year ago. You can make sure by visiting these questions. https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/does-the-stackexchange-community-certify-the-active-and-ranked-people-per-month and https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/badges-in-stackexchange . A year ago, Do you think I knew that elections would be held this month especially since it was not held for four years :)

Comment: Most (if not all) of Your mindset is on scoring, points, badges and rewards and MVP ship. Most of SO Users do not give a shit about rewards, all they want is an answer.  Summed in one graph: [**Leaderboard**](http://www.gamification.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Leaderboard.png)  Take a Octalysis course and learn people want way more: http://yukaichou.com/gamification-examples/octalysis-complete-gamification-framework/

Comment: @M.Qassas - You have been a top contributor for almost a year. So once you become a moderator, how will it affect your contribution to the site ?  How do you intend to balance moderation activities and contribution to site, specifically answering questions ?

Comment: Dear @GautamSheth Thank you so much for your valuable questions. Regarding: How will it affect your contribution to the site? 

As you said my bro I have been a top contributor for almost a year with 53 badges for editing, moderation, and other badges. However, this is not effected on my other responsibilities like my work and my family. so any new responsibility is just required to know How to manage your time and specify the priority and severity of each job you will do!

Comment: To be honest. Moderation job will require additional effort and time but it worth that. and I think I can manage this based on my success story in the community for almost a year :) I believe Allah burdens not a person beyond his scope.so in case, I selected as moderator I am pretty sure I put in this position because I am able to do it :) in case, I am not selected I will congratulate the winners and continue my lovely contribution to this awesome community :)

Comment: Regarding: How do you intend to balance moderation activities and contribution to the site, specifically answering questions?

I think moderation activities will increase my answering contribution, I will be responsible for staying more time and checking most of the questions. so based on my humble knowledge I will try to continue answering questions more than before :) because I love what I do this is the secret :)

Comment: One thing that concerns me is: you have done very little moderating when it comes to reviews. Waqas is almost the top of the leaderboard on every category, but seems as though you haven't done nearly any reviewing over 1 year here. How can we assume that will change with a moderator badge?

Comment: Hi @Mike, I appreciate your valuable concern, I would like to remember you that I have been in this community for almost a year and I think it is not a long period, meanwhile, I am trying to do my best and I think I achieved some good achievements, compared to those who joined a year ago.

Comment: let's now talk about numbers, I got three moderation badge in a year. besides the following

906 answers
916 Posts
~162k people reached
1150 profile views
Visited 328 days, 313 consecutive. I'm here every day
724 posts edited
227 helpful flags
1,163 Comments
1,174 Revisions
429 votes
536 reviews
230 Suggestions
17,112 total reputations
Top 11 contributors of all times
2nd top contributor in 2016
1st top contributor in 26 weeks, 7 months, 3rd, 4th quarter of 2016
1st top answers for Project Server, PWA and MS Project tags
53 Badges.3 Gold,10 Silver,40 Bronze.

Comment: Although you have described these numbers as a little but what about my joining date? I think these achievements have been achieved within a year is considered not bad effort.meanwhile, I am trying my best, If I see any review opportunity, I complete it. I promise If I am elected or not, I will increase this rate :)

Comment: By the way, It is an honor for me to compare waqas achievements to me, but to be fair, I think that waqas has joined this community for more than 3 years. so It is better to compare his achievements to you, you also have great achievements and joined 7 years ago and despite that, he is the top one in all categories as you have said :)

Finally, I really respect your concern and hope to you good luck to be a moderator you deserve that :)

Answer (score 15):

I am **Waqas Sarwar**, I will try to answer the below questions.

> 1. How would you improve the voting rate on the site? Since the famous meta post [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters) was asked back in 2013 I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes. Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio. How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the site?

That is tough question, I feel the same way. Couple of things I have in my mind.

- As a moderator I will get more powers then regular users so i will read all Q & A related to my field if that marked as answer i will upvote it. that's little effort from my side.
- Also encourage the asking person if he can upvote and also tell him this is important.
- I feel another thing, 1st timer user even do have enough reputation to do upto so i will discuss this with moderators how we can make it better. At-least grant the upvote rights the user who asked the question without reputation constraint.
- I think, we should also think about sending a alert to the user that if any of the reply resolve the issue or help u resolve ur problem than please upvote it and mark it answer.
- Running a competition attract more users to go for voting.
- now a days I noticed couple of community running their own MVP awards ( c-sharpcorner, codeproject), we should also think about it.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

- I will follow the community rule and also talk to him in a chat room. I will also discuss it with my fellow moderators to make a decision. All the time teamwork helps to resolve the issue in better way

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

- Always the respect other opinion but it is not necessary that we agree with others opinion. If I feel it that question should not deleted then i will use the dispute option and also discuss with moderator. i will act accordingly after the all options.

> 4. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

- what i believe, other than the task I can do ( review, upvote, editing, Answering etc), they help the new users to feel welcome in the SE, planning & discussion with back-end people to improve the SE 
  Monitoring spamming or abusing of the system. encourage others to join the community, make efforts to make this place one of the best community

> 5. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

- It will be great honor have diamond with my name but this also give me more responsibility then a regular users, because now everything I say will be accounted. Users follow the moderators, If one action is acceptable from a moderator then it will be from me.
  It will be great as I love helping others without hurting ego.

> 6. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

couple of things i feel
 - no limit on voting ( that is the only time when i feel i am stuck)
 - back end access
 - More powers than regular user, Moderators dont need extra vote to close a question.
 - future Planning for community improvement
 - moderators discussion 
 - Much more which i even dont know.

Comment: Same question as I asked Mohammed. WHY do you want to be a moderator? You DO have [all moderation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) already because you have 25K+ points, Why haven't you used those powers before? and Why would getting the title "Moderator" change you behaviour?

Comment: i think i already answer that question, if you read it. it is honor. Yes it give us more powers but with responsibility. Responsibilities always changes one's behavior. some time you have to give the powers to moderators to make decision. I think, i have to skills and attitude to work with team to improve the community. I used the powers which i gain with 25K, i am sure my numbers reflect it.

Comment: *"Sometime you have to give the powers to moderators to make decision"* Can you give an example for user post(s) in the past where you would have acted different if you had had the Moderator Title (you have the power already)

Comment: I don't have example but there are many scenario,I do not know who is up voting on the replies,may be two user just abuse the system and up vote on each other...that's where u need moderator power to check that...also for making improvement decision u need moderator power

Comment: So you think UpVotes are abused? You are after the persons who abuse SO? When in power you are going to check UpVotes and see who misbehaved and act upon your findings?

Comment: I think if user A is upvote only on User B's reply then yes it is abuse, in my understanding. that's how I learned from different communities. I am sure there will be a way as moderator to check it. If I get elected then yes i will follow the SE guideline and act accordingly. it is not my decision, it is SE's guideline. If i think we should improve, i will raise my concern.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman It might seem that a 25k user already have access to all moderations privileges, but that's not the real truth. 25k users can only cast votes on deletion, and not delete by themselves. But Waqas has participated greatly in flagging content in need of moderator action, which is very helpful. Also, the review queue makes a huge difference on moderator impact, and so far - Waqas have made great contribution.

Comment: Moderators must carry great responsibilities in terms of their **behavior**, **communication skills**, and **how smartly they handle conflicts or difference of opinion with good and polite language**. Do you think you need any improvement in these points? Will you be able to do justice to the community? Do you have ability to be polite and calm nature when needed?

Comment: There is an influx of Asian located people into SO, it seems they skip the search/read introduction part and question quality is low. How are you going to moderate that? And wouldn't it be better to assign a similar-cultured person (you are in the USA) to that job then? Would also help with the time-zone difference.

Comment: How do you see being moderator in both MS SP forums and in SO SP forums would work out?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP - Once you become a moderator, how will it affect your contribution to the site ?  How do you intend to balance moderation activities and contribution to site, specifically answering questions ?

Comment: @Jussi Palo. Mods on MS SP forums does not required many efforts as compare to SE. MSFT also have their employee doing the Mods on those forums as their job duty. Over there as moderators, our task is very limited as compare to SE. I am active on both forums since 2013 and I have good balance on both side. You can see statistics under my profile, how am I performing. I think, I have a God gifted quality called parallel processing that is why I am successful at my job. I use these forums to increase my knowledge and stay up to date on my area of expertise. Therefore, I am confident I can do it.

Comment: @Gautam Sheth. Thank you for asking this. If I become moderator then I think my contribution will increased, because I have to monitor the posts which give me opportunity  to respond on the post if that belong to my area. Currently, I am not monitoring every post so I miss many question, which belongs to my area of expertise. So, I am confident that my contribution will be increasing with quality work.

Comment: @Asad Rafi. I agree with you that moderators bring more responsibilities. I think this is main skill everyone should have to participate in the communities because without being nice you will not survive. May be couple of user accept it but rude attitude never long lasting. I try my best to being nice with everyone (you can check my discussion with different people especially in chat rooms). Being nice is a key to success in everyday’ s life. In my opinion, I always have room for improvement and learn new things. continue to next comment.....

Comment: ----These communities’ contributions always teaches me good stuff. All I can say, what I am doing is in good faith without any interest other gaining knowldge. User can disagree with my opinion and I am open to listen and correct myself.

Comment: @Danny I think labeling one geographic people with low quality question is not right, as I am seeing the same behavior from around the globe. To handle the low quality questions, we always flag it and leave a comment to ask for more information, which is what I am doing. I asked them add more details in your question/answer so that other can understand it better. I think SE is doing good job on low quality/link only/duplicate posts. For me similar- cultured will not make any difference. BTW, I am also from Asia pacific region and settled in USA in 2008, for your concern I am same culture zone.

Comment: Yes, the whole world is asking low quality questions.. I asked @20000 unanswered Qs (just over a year ago) what we are going to do about it... the number is nearing 25000 now. 5000 questions in a year... no actions whatsoever..And those numbers will only increase.  I refer to India in particular because those (millions) are educated in English so there is no barrier to ask a question. The moment Microsofts Translation services run IN Browsers we will we see another influx of people who don't even have to write in English anymore becuase everything will be transalated on the spot.

Comment: Instead of electing one or two extra janitors this community is better of with clear leadership. Every first post should get a comment , (once more) directing them to a clear 1 Wiki page with 5 Tips to get the best out of SO: 1) use descriptive subject and clear question 2) refer to other SO questions and blogposts you tried 3) show and format (short snippets) of code 4) read 1 to 3 again 5) and read them once more

Comment: Again it is your opinion that every unanswered question is low quality. A question is unanswered because no one know the solution for that siutiotion and as per SE policy (As SE is not vendor of SharePoint, AS MSFT has a policy close the question by marking them as answer after two weeks to improve their support score which I disagree) that dont give powers to Mods to close a questions. We have a set of rule if a question pass that then that question no more low quality. If a question clear all the reviews then it does not matter whether it is from native english speaker or not---

Comment: ---, question is question. SE is global forum so every should have rights to ask, we are here to help them in every role (as a Mod or as a regular users). this is what we all doing here, you trying to raise your concerns and we trying to answer it. It does not matter i get elected or not, for me most important thing is helping other to get peace. There is always a room to improve the process which i believe current mods doing and future mods will also....If you have good idea and can improve why not you nominate yourself and help the community.

Comment: You are missing the point. People ask Bad questions. I am not saying to ban them, I am saying instead of SO janitors there should de SO Teachers. We don't have to treat them as children, we do have to encourage them to get a license.

Comment: with due respect but i disagree with it, If a question pass all the review flags then it will not called bad or low quality.  Again no question is small, we can improve our processes and more vigilant but if a question pass all the checks then it is legitimate question. an open question already on meta site related to your concern. https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/best-practice-for-question-with-no-answer I agree we should have more help material like wiki page, how to videos for users training.

Comment: what about duplicate, or very similar answers? Are those subject to moderation?

Comment: @Mike, Good point. Well, that is really tough because in SharePoint infrastructure for multiple problems we have same solutions....Like IISreset or clear config cache. So in my opinion, review on question more important.,

Comment: those aren't similar. I'm talking about revising another answer and making it your own but changing a few lines of code.

Comment: It is matter of morality, user who copy the code from others should give the credit original author. Honestly, it is really hard to catch the pirated content and I dont think if Mod has some kind of tool to check these type of posts.

Comment: I'm not talking about pirating, I'm saying a similar answer, but just revising it to make it a little different as another answer. Same exactly concept, but more code

Comment: that is normal practice, everyone get the code from internet and edit it as per the requirement. Unless content are protected under the some kind of license. Otherwise people dont want reinvent wheel. It is hard to monitor these type of posts.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say. Nevermind.

Comment: I am sorry for it. what I understand. If you respond on a question and I respond on the same question with information from your reponse plus add some in it. is it right? right?

Comment: It concerns me that your grammar skills are tough to read. Explain how you can be a good moderator when your writing skills can be difficult to understand, or your comprehension of others' English is sub par?

Comment: English grammar is must have skill, but this is a technical forum not an English language forum (there are two forums https://english.stackexchange.com/, https://ell.stackexchange.com/). That's why I was able to help a lot of users (impact 1.8 Millions) successfully.  You can see grammar issue in Microsoft Technet articles. I know my skills is not upto PAR as a native English speaker but still I am able to help & resolve others issues.

Comment: I always improving my skills, grammar as well as technical. I always look for learning opportunity.

Comment: Waqas, please don't think I'm picking on you. You've been a huge asset to this community, and you are truly a role model for moderation. I commend your honesty. In the past you have really helped me with answering questions I had. I just hope to see your grammar improve.

Comment: No man, i am not thinking that way. I always appreciate the others opinion and i am just explaining what I am thinking. I may be wrong on my stand but my end goal is help others. No personal feeling just a Q & A thing. I am feeling i am in the US's presidential debate. But i am sure, at least I will get vote from you.

Answer (score 13):

I'm [Arsalan Adam Khatri](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4100/arsalan-adam-khatri), here are the answers to given questions:

> 1. How would you improve the voting rate on the site? Since the famous meta post Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters? was asked back in 2013 I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes. Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio. How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the site?

Agree to that, I'm also a lazy voter myself. I think the main reason for this is that SharePoint is very diverse in nature and although I'm working on SharePoint since 2010, there are many areas for me which are still untouched. And I think this effects voting, I can't vote on a question/answer that I don't understand.

Also on this community, mostly people are not concerned with voting, reputation etc. They usually get to this community to ask a problem they are having, once they have the answer to it, poof they are gone. So these are usually new users and I think somewhere on the Ask Question screen or right next to the tags in the question we should show a message which goes like if your problem is resolved from any of the answers, you should upvote or select it as an answer (we can revise the message if needed to be more effective). This can appear only to the questioner.

However I do redirect many users who ask anything from me regarding SharePoint to this community and do tell them all the rules about upvoting or selecting an answer to close the question. That I can do without being a moderator too :)

One more thing that bugs me is the questions which are open to discussion or are opinion based, these are the questions I like the most, but they tend to be closed because of their nature. SharePoint is different and yes opinion based questions should be allowed, I don't know how will I change this as a moderator. But definitely that area needs some working.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Well if the user is giving valuable answers, he is an asset to the community and must be retained at all costs. Also if that's his nature, we can't change that either. So reviewing his flags unbiasly, giving him a proper comment to not get involved in such arguments should be the best bet. We can however ignore his behavior until it gets worse. And I will definitely hope it doesn't get to that point.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

This is my favorite question out of all, because many questions I think should not be closed; usually get closed. Most of which are based on opinion or discussion. As I said SharePoint is different and such questions should be allowed, obviously if they not completely go against the rules of community.

People can have difference of opinion and we should respect eachothers opinion but there is always a room for discussion. So I will discuss such questions with fellow moderators and if any rule can be applied where they can remain Open, we do apply that rule otherwise will go with the fellow moderators decision.

> 4. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Well I don't know what powers are given to moderators, but they review our flags, they settle any disputes, have authority to cancel or abandon someone's account (not sure) or give warnings etc.

So mainly they are responsible to keep the harmony on the community, they are usually involved where human behavior kicks in. Because SO is a strong platform and content integrity is mostly handled with AI or rest of the active members (where they flag, or review).

> 5. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

Well that is a great responsibility. I have to think twice maybe thrice before posting anything as a comment, question or answer. That's why I have been on this community for such a long time before nominating myself as a moderator, I did nominate myself in the last election but I withdrew the nomination for the same reason, as I thought I was not ready for such a responsibility.

But now I think I have spent a lot of time learning from existing moderators on how to tackle different situations and need their support if I get elected. So how do I feel, nervous but very excited.

> 6. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

With great responsibility comes great power. So although reaching to any specific number in terms of reputation was never my intention. I just wanted to help and get helped where needed, that's why I joined the community and yes I have learnt a lot on this community. And I can guarantee that becoming a moderator will not change that, I will definitely answer or ask questions which is the core of this community.

I would like to answer some other questions which are asked with other nominees:

> WHY?

I definitely don't know, I was thinking since about 3 days why am I nominating myself as a moderator because I think I'm doing a good job without being one. But I saw other nominees and I felt like I should be nominating myself, not that other nominees don't deserve but if they do, I do too!

Again the reason to join this community is to help and get helped. Being a moderator will not change that, but definitely once I become I will share it with people around me, maybe post something on LinkedIn or Facebook, not to showoff but that will be out of excitement.

> Moderators must carry great responsibilities in terms of their behavior, communication skills, and how smartly they handle conflicts or difference of opinion with good and polite language. Do you think you need any improvement in these points? Will you be able to do justice to the community? Do you have ability to be polite and calm nature when needed?

As I have already expressed, I feel being a moderator is a great responsibility and yes I will have to think many times before posting anything or making any decision.

But yes I have very polite and calm nature and I don't get burst out of anger or any other emotion. Being here for 5 years, I have never been into any argument and yes I think I will be able to do justice to the community.

Any other questions are welcome!

Comment: You have my top vote, as grammar is an extreme pet peeve of mine--and your grammar skills are stellar.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but my vocabulary is very weak. Between why aren't you participating in the election? You will make a good candidate!

Comment: I'll have to think about it. I may still nominate myself, but I want to see who else will step up to the plate.

Comment: Yes do nominate yourself and you will have my upvote :)

Answer (score 12):

Here are my answers:

> How would you improve the voting rate on the site? Since the famous
>   meta post Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters? was asked back in 2013
>   I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and
>   answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes.
>   Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio.
>   How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the
>   site?

Well, I think SharePoint, by nature, is a smaller community--we just have to embrace the fact that sometimes SharePoint is a side project. That being said, encourage well thought out posts with **CLEAR** questions and answers, and be helpful for newcomers and veterans alike to follow the rules and make good contributions. Other than that, if users are lazy to vote, there is no way to force them to vote other than a simple reminder every now and then to vote.

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

Possibly have a chat with him or her. It depends on the situation what is being flagged. It also could be some tension with another user. Good content is what brings traffic to the site and builds up the knowledgebase of SP.SE, but following the rules and being respectful is equally as important.

Moderators have the ability to [privately message](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/02/moderator-messages/) those who they need to talk to about a situation. This can be crucial in times of repeat offenses, site misconduct and misuse, and other topics that deem moderators using this method.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Talk to the mod about why. I could have missed a reason why he/she thought to close it, but if we have a difference of opinion, we ask for a third vote from another moderator. There can be a chatroom discussion. It would be extremely taboo to have moderators arguing about a topic. It's bad. It's ugly. It's incredibly unattractive. That should be done out of view.

When in doubt, there is usually a rule that can back up any justified moderation. Whether that is closing a question or removing an invalid answer, or anything inbetween, usually there is a rule that governs what and why.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Keep questions, answers, comments, and other content **CLEAR** and **STRUCTURED** in a respectful fashion, which brings good content, good well thought-out questions and answers, good feedback, and is also great for searchability.

Moderators must have several key traits in order to be successful:

- They must be **FAIR**. Treating everyone with the same respect and courteousness, from veterans to new users. No favoritism or unequal treatment if an issue or situation arises.
- They must be **CONSISTENT**. All rules must be followed everyday, for every user. If there is a decision made on how to govern tags, questions, answers, or other moderation tasks, it must be universally carried out--even to other moderators.
- They must **GUIDE**. That includes showing all users HOW to best use the site and to keep it's integrity and structure. It also means to be a role model for others looking to stay on the site. As a moderator, your moderation badge is tied to everything, so you must be an avid user and lead by example.
- They must be **DEDICATED**. That means dedicated to stay an active moderator for the time period the system allots. I've been here for **7 years**, which should be a testament of the dedication I have.

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the
>   past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will
>   do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

No problem with me. I think my behavior here has been more than reasonable. Everyone here has been great, polite, and reasonable with their actions. In the 7 years I've been here, I've only seen mods ban 2 people for misconduct. I don't see that kind of behavior here often, but it does happen from time to time. As a moderator you must learn how to diffuse those situations and react in a manner that reflects positively for SP.SE.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Reputation has to do with asking and answering questions, which sometimes is a game of chase. Sometimes I don't know the answer off the bat, sometimes someone else has a similar answer, other times I enjoy making questions and answers more clear for others to answer. Reputation isn't as important to me than building good content for this knowledgebase.

Anyone can have a good amount of reputation because of the questions and answers he/she contributes to the site. A moderator will be the guiding light and a lead example of a great contributor.

**Endnote**:

> I'm a stickler for grammar and I feel strong grammar skills are
>   essential in keeping content understandable and reduced the amount of
>   fluff in the comments asking about clarification and gets to the point
>   quicker. If users come to the site and are immediately confused about
>   the explanation of the question, the answers will be fewer. If answers
>   are hard to understand, more comments will be generated and usually
>   users will be deterred to answer a question if there are multiple
>   questions available already--even if those answers are unclear. My point is to  moderate those questions/answers/comments in order to make them more clear.

Comment: Great, how you can help new users like me?

Comment: Welcome! I would encourage good answers, precise questions, and helpful comments. We welcome you to contribute and add to the site we are all part of! The neat part about Stack Exchange is that it gives new users a good amount of tools to do some light moderation already, such as flagging, participating in meta, voting, and creating wikis